# Alternative biology/Xenoforming 3:any ideas how to xenoform Mars?

Tags: biology, planets, xenobiology, aliens, terraforming

So i have an idea of an super advanced being that travels around the galaxy and spreads life on every planet that has any potential for it.By "life"i do not mean only "Carbon based"life,but any lifeform that would be suited for a particular planet.So if a planet is difficult to terraform into,say,Carbon based enviroment it gets modified to that other,exotic (for us...)life may flourish.This being comes into our Solar system and starts to xenoform (modify planets to fit other alien lifeforms' needs)various planets and moons.

My question is:do you guys have any ideas to "xenoform" Mars?

I asked similar questions about The Moon and Venus.Feel free to check my other posts !

Comment: It would be a really good idea to read the comments on your posts. Also, [edit] to make them one question per post as you've been advised.

Comment: Same problem as your other two posts. You need to explain the specific target for xenoforming to comply with our [help] rules.

Comment: The title says Mars, the text says Mercury. They are not the same. And asking what kind of atmosphere would be needed without saying for what it would be needed is not conducive to receiving good answers.

Comment: Oh sorry i originally wanted to ask about Mercury but wrote Mars instead.So i will ask about Mercury in another post,and i will try to limit my question.I already edited this post.

Comment: Quite pointless question, whatever u may think of can be made(or not,lol; no it can be made) and any planet contains plenty of stuff for that, even a gas giant u may think it 90 hydrogen and 9 percent helium and thus can't host anything, but that's not true for cases when evolutions has no place but creation has. All u candidates has the same problem. Life can exist in any celestial body in this system, if it is made. "Gime ideas" is a trigger word here, maybe a better would be "how to approach problem of generation created life for different planet conditions for reason lalala"

Comment: VTO despite comment above, it indeed a problem for an unprepared human to figure out a thing for the conditions which makes sense. It isn't an easy question and one who would like to provide sciencifically plausible yes or no answers should be able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### They smelted the planet

Mars contains much iron complexed with oxygen.  The aliens converted much of it to reduced (pure) iron and moved it deep into the planet's core.  Additionally, they heated or otherwise converted CaCO3 and [MgCO3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonates_on_Mars) to CaO and MgO, and vaporized any water and dry ice near the surface.  Last but not least, they used their heating process to restart the Martian plate tectonics and engineered a series of volcanic apertures whereby remnant gas could be emitted from the core.

I'm not sure how much CO2 they needed to liberate to bring Mars into the liquid water range.  Venus has 90 bars of it and +480 K to its equilibrium temperature, but raising it 0.01% of a bar on Earth seems to be good for something on the order of a kelvin.  The absorbance must reach a maximum at some point.  So if I say Mars needs to warm by 78 K to be like Earth, it doesn't really need 15 bars of CO2, but something substantially less.  How much less I'm not sure.

Totally at a guess, as a starting point, let's suppose they make Mars with 5 atm of CO2 and 5 atm of O2, slightly cooler than Earth, with a small northern ocean that is usually frozen over - reducing the H2 loss to space.  Organic matter in this environment is absurdly flammable - worse than Apollo 1 - so Earthlike carbon based life is found only in the ocean.  The abnormally high level of dissolved oxygen (in proportion to the atmospheric O2) permits more active sea life than we see on Earth.

On dry land, oxides predominate - the planet is designed as a supremely oxidizing environment due to the high O2 level.  Lipid membranes, and lipids, are right out of consideration.  Sulfate, carbonate, phosphate, nitrate ... the aliens have lifeforms that work with these units in novel combinations, linked by shared oxygens, unfamiliar to Earthly biochemistry, and in some ways more similar to silicon-based life since there is an oxygen between most other atoms.  I doubt they are very advanced lifeforms, but the aliens could cherish their opportunity to build a diverse collection.